# Check out Page Issue - reloading twice Magento 2.1.7

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7

I Don't know why Commented code working in magento 2.1.7 I have used reload script for some reason but not required now. so i have commented that code. Even the Checkout page refreshing twice after clicking NEXT button.

If I remove that commented code page won't work. Kindly Help....
I am stuck on this As i am newbie.

```
    <div id="checkout" data-bind="scope:'checkout'" class="checkout-container">
    <div id="checkout-loader" data-role="checkout-loader" class="loading-mask" data-mage-init='{"checkoutLoader": {}}'>
        <div class="loader">
            <img src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>"
                 alt="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Loading...'); ?>"
                 style="position: absolute;">
        </div>
    </div> 
<!--     <button type="button" onClick="window.location.reload();" rtfdfgfghfghvalue='Check Pincode Availablity'>Click to Check Pincode Availablity</button> -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko --> <!-- by satish 24.09.2017 -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {   
            "#checkout": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        window.checkoutConfig = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo \Zend_Json::encode($block->getCheckoutConfig()); ?>;
        // Create aliases for customer.js model from customer module
        window.isCustomerLoggedIn = window.checkoutConfig.isCustomerLoggedIn;
        window.customerData = window.checkoutConfig.customerData;
    </script>
    <script>
        require([
            'mage/url',
            'Magento_Ui/js/block-loader'
        ], function(url, blockLoader) {
            blockLoader("<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>");
            return url.setBaseUrl('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getBaseUrl();?>');
        })
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share website URL, did you flushed cache and static content deploy after done those changes?

Comment: Yes i done cache flush , static content deploy url is shopkeeperz.com

Comment: Did you tried after delete that code?

Comment: yes i removed commented code than checkout page coming blank

Comment: When going through buy now button its happening i used plugin of prince from github

Comment: have you tried with the private window? because it is working fine for me.

Comment: i tried in private window its happening when i am clicking on buy now button. other wise its working fine if i am going through "GO To Checkout button"

Comment: I think issue related to chat box some time it adds multiple I-frame and sometimes 1 only. website reload each time while adding new I-frame in the checkout page.

Comment: Ok i will disable the chat box plugin hope this will solve my issue.

Comment: Please add loader image it will help to customers to identify something is loading in the background.

Comment: Disabling Chat box plugin doesn't worked. now i removed commented code working but same issue reloading twice.

Comment: @ssatish4u Did you resolved this issue ?? Can you please tell me how you resolved it. Facing same issue.

Comment: Please add loader image it will help to customers to identify something is loading in the background this will solve the issue or change the landing url